# Keeping track of an HTML5 variable in SCORM -Part II

Tags: html, scorm

I work with HTML5 and JavaScript as SCORM packages in Moodle (LMS). I'm looking for ways to transfer data reliably.

A previous query asked about using a SCORM package to store a variable in a CMI. One answer involved using a SCORM variable described as CMIIdentifier. (SCORM 1.2 spec.)

What is/what is the size of "CMIIdentifier"?

Answer (score 0):

Things that are of type CMIIdentifier are a max of 255 characters. Fair warning, CMIIdentifier can't have anything but alphanumeric characters - no spaces, no 'unprintable characters'.

If you're looking to store larger data look at cmi.suspend_data (4096 char string).

You can grab the specs here https://adlnet.gov/research/scorm/scorm-1-2/ . You'll find info on data types and data elements in the Run-Time Environment book.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, cmi.objectives.n.id (for example, decribed as a CMIIdentifier variable under Scorm 1.2) allows a user to R/W transfer/store 255 alphanumeric characters (no spaces, as you state) for each created created "n" page.